# How to make a MongoDB connection Exception?

Tags: java, mongodb, exception, try-catch

I made an app that parses news from NewsAPI and saves them into a MongoDB collection. What I want to do is make the application work even if the Mongo Service is not up (or if the user doesn't have mongo installed.) Here's the code:

```
try{
    // mongo connection methods
    // mongo saving files method
}
catch(MongoSocketOpenException e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

I surrounded the connection with a try-catch, but if the mongo service is not opened, it still doesn't work... because the mongo exceptions are imported only when the service is opened. How do i have to do this? Exception e is not working... MongoSocketOpenException neither... Thanks for the help. Here's the error i receive if the service is closed.

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.0.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.0.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.0.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.0.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.0.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.0.jar:na]
... 3 common frames omitted
```

Thanks for the effort. :)

Comment: You want to make your connection throw exceptions? Do I understand it right? Why?

Comment: Because if the connection is unavailable, the app would still work

Comment: So it shouldn't work? This is something different than you initially asked then. You asked how to **make** your connection throw exception. You can do that by breaking connection parameters, it's quite simple, in fact. However. If your app shouldn't work if no connection available, then you have to replace code in catch block with something that would tell about the problem to the user, and then somehow make related app functionality inaccessible (for instance, shut it down, though that's a bad look). Just printing out the message won't help with that.

Comment: no, the app must work even if it can't connect... simply it will skip the mongo connection and make other stuff...

Comment: That's even more confusing. Do you, or do you not want your app to continue working if connection is unavailable? Can you please attach a detailed [mcve] and exception stack traces you're getting (if any)?

Comment: ok, i'm sorry. I'll explain better

Comment: hope i'ts enough comprehensible now :)

Comment: OK, so assuming your app just reads files from some API and saves them to Mongo, what would constitute as a "working app" if it can't save the files? I.e. what else is there, and why *that* requires a mongo connection?

Comment: simply, the app will send in output on localhost the parsed articles. I just want to know how to handle this exception D:

Comment: Since you're saying that no mongo connection is OK, then logging the exception and continuing is fine.

Comment: if i put exception e, it doesn't work D:

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any of your code frames in attached stack trace. Either that means you've attached an incomplete error log, or this exception is not the result of your code, rather the result of your configuration.

Comment: you maybe didn't understand my problem. I want to make the app run even if mongo is not installed in the pc. HOW do i have to do to make it happen? I totally know the Exception I'm trying to catch doesn't work....

Comment: I'm just saying that after half a week we're still discussing a snippet of code that consists of a single `try/catch` block. It'd probably be faster for you at this point to debug the whole driver library step by step and ssee how you can disable avoid trying to connect to it or something.